# How to trigger OnMouseX events on Kinematic Rigidbody2D object with a different collider than one used for collisions?

Tags: unity

I have a use-case where I have an object with a Collider2D and a Kinematic RigidBody2D in order to do Kinematic movement.

However, I also want to be able to select/hover that object with a OnMouseDown/OnMouseEnter/etc, using a larger collider than I would use for the kinematic movement.

My current attempt at a solution is to have Physics-related scripts/rigidbody2d/collider2d as the top level game object, and to have a child object, with a larger collider2D which will respond to OnMouseX events.

[image]

[image] [image]

In order to ignore OnMouseX events on the parent, I'm putting it into its own `user_ignore_raycasts` layer (I need it as its own layer for the layer collision matrix). I'm also putting the child in its own `user_use_raycasts` layer.

I'm passing that into a script that sets MainCamera's event mask:
[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
 
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraEventMasker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask cameraEventMask;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().eventMask = cameraEventMask;
    }
}
```

What I notice is that OnMouseX events on the child will work IF the RigidBody2D on the parent is deleted...however, if the RigidBody2D is there, I won't receive any events. Anyone know why this is the case, and if there are other workarounds or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

My 3d game objects often would have multiple colliders - one on the parent for selecting/clicking, and others on children for such things as vision (detecting enemies), for detecting range, etc.

For clicking/selecting I use *Physics.Raycast*.

**Similarly this should work for your 2d project:**

you write this script in your *Update()* function.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
    {
        Vector3 origin0 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hitn = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(origin0.x, origin0.y), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask);

        if (hitn.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("I clicked on: " + hitn.transform.name);
        }
    }
```

This script shoots 2D ray at mouse click (or touch) point and if it detects 2D collider, returns it.

Note the variable *layerMask*. You can create public variable layerMask and add to it layers which you want to be 'clickable' - other layers will be ignored. Thus you can have a game object with one 'clickable' 2d collider, and in children you can have as much colliders as you want doing other things - just put those children in other layer (or layers).

```
public LayerMask layerMask;
```